# How to use SQLiteAsyncConnection from the async PCL version of SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using a PCL version of Sqlite.net from https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

However, I'm unable to get the DB connection setup. The `SQliteAsyncConnection` does unlike the original version not take a string (path to the DB), but a `[Func< SQLiteConnectionWithLock>.]`[2](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net.Async/SQLiteAsyncConnection.cs#L39)

How can this be used?
In general: how to use this library? I have a core PCL lib which does all the business logic from my iOS, Android and WP8 projects. My understanding was that I can drop the the Sqlite-Net Async PCL into my PCL lib. But it seems like I have to provide some platform specific stuff to get it to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to create a function that returns a `SQLiteConnectionWithLock` and pass that to the `SQLiteAsyncConnection` constructor.

```
string databasePath = "path";
var connectionFactory = new Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>(()=>new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), new SQLiteConnectionString(databasePath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false)));
var asyncConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(connectionFactory);
```

Comment: Where does `SQLitePlatformWinRT`come from? Separate package? Does it work for WP8 too / is there an implementation?

Comment: I mixed up WinRT and WP8 in your question. There is `SQLitePlatformWP8CSharp` in the `SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.CSharpSqlite` namespace

Comment: The code doesn't have any errors but the database is not created. Why?

Comment: thank you!  man this was hard to find.  All the docs everywhere else seem to imply you can just create a `SQLiteAsyncConnection` with a database path.

Comment: Any ideas on how to customize the connection string? I want to use custom PRAGMAS.

Comment: Likewise, thanks. Documentation for this otherwise apparently useful library is woefully inadequate.

Comment: You'll eventually hit an SQLite busy exception if your connection factory continually hands out new connections ... you may be better of creating a single connection, and have the connection factory return that.

Comment: How to read a password protected sqlite database using this method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems with this too. To meet Johnbot's answer which is correct I am adding how I have used this library and got it to work. I did not really understand the NuGet packages, so I did it manually.

1. Download the project 
   https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL
2. Load the solution in VS2015, set to release mode and create the dlls for:

a) SQLite.Net

b) SQLite.Net.Async

c) SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT which is for Windows 10 universal apps, or the platform you need.

Ensure you have these references in your project.

[image: references]

SQLIte for Universal App is installed from VS Tools / Extensions and Updates. Once installed it is referenced under Universal Windows / Extensions along with the Visual C++ 2015 which is also required.

Good luck!

Comment: Do I need to have the WinRT platform? I only want to develop towards android and ios

Comment: Time has moved on and I now use only SQlite.Net-PCL,  I no longer use the Sqlite async calls, but make async  functions in C# if needed. Excuse me but I am not yet coding for IOS and android, hope this helps;